# Azure Storage Explorer - Unable to list resources

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

Granted **Reader** & **Storage Blob Data Reader** Role access on Azure Data Lake Gen2 Storage Account to the user **DataLakeTester**

[image]

Also under Manage Access granted full rights on Access / Default section.

[image]

But when logged into  into Azure Storage Explorer with above user, is successfully connected to the data lake but cannot list the containers and throw below error.  Is there some other role assignment to be done?

[image]

Comment: the mask limits access for named users, the owning group, and named groups. Data Lake Storage Gen1 account, the mask for the Access ACL of the root folder ("/") defaults to RWX.

Comment: The role `Reader` should be assigned at the storage account, not the container, try that.

Comment: @Joy Wang:  Sorry Reader  access was at Storage level.

Comment: It works fine on my side, could you try to sign out and sign in again? Note: Make sure the error was caused by click `Blob Containers`, not the file, table, queue.

Comment: "Reader" and "Storage Blob Data Reader" do not provide the permissions the error message says it needs. You need List Keys permissions Or you need a role that lets you list containers

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Storage Explore now available is 1.11.1. Please update and try again:https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/releases

In response to your query:

But when logged into Azure Storage Explorer with above user, is successfully connected to the data lake but cannot list the containers and throw below error. Is there some other role assignment to be done? It works fine on my side, could you try to sign out and sign in again?

The RBAC roles you have appear to be sufficient. It can take some time for RBAC changes to propagate. So accessing things in Storage Explorer might not work as expected for a few minutes.